# Showing f(1/n) is Cauchy, given |f'(x)|=<1

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : (0, 1] → R$ with $|f'(x)| ≤ 1$ for $x ∈ (0, 1)$. Show that the sequence $f(1/n)_{n∈N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and hence has a limit.

I don't see how the derivative being less than 1 implies a limit.

Answer (score 2):

By the mean value theorem, it follows that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le |x - y|$ for all $x,y \in (0,1]$. Thus $|f(1/n) - f(1/m)| \le |1/n - 1/m| \to 0$ as $n,m\to \infty$. This implies $f(1/n)$ is Cauchy in $\Bbb R$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(1/n)$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

When $|f'(x)|\leq 1$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|$ (a consequence of the mean value theorem) so $|f(1/n)-f(1/m)|\leq |1/m-1/n|$ and you're almost done